# How to show original image and blurred image in JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage, blur, convolution

I have two images in my JFrame. The first is the original and I want the second image to be blurred. I have both images being reflected in the frame but the second is not blurred. How can I code this program better to reflect a blurred image?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String path = "src/logo.jpg";
            File file = new File(path);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(label);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocation(0,200);
            f.setVisible(true);

            String path2 = "src/logo.jpg";
            File file2 = new File(path2);
            BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(file2);
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image2));
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(label2);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocation(200,200);
            f.setVisible(true);

            float[] matrix = new float[400];
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
                matrix[i] = 1.0f/400.0f;

            BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(20, 20, matrix), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null );
            image2 = op.filter(image, null);

        }}
```

Also my location of the second image is off and not even with the first image. My setLocation should have both images side by side with space in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the first label to the `BorderLayout.WEST` position and the second to the `BorderLayout.EAST` position
2. Add the result of the blur operation to the second label, not the original image. The blur operation creates a new image

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String path = "src/logo.jpg";
            File file = new File(path);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

            String path2 = "src/logo.jpg";
            File file2 = new File(path2);
            BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(file2);

            float[] matrix = new float[400];
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
                matrix[i] = 1.0f/400.0f;

            BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(20, 20, matrix), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null );
            image2 = op.filter(image, null);
            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image2));
             f.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

             f.pack();
             f.setVisible(true);

        }
```