# How can I make the 'fillRect' or 'fillOval' in Java Swing blurry?

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a rectangle, or even an oval, have a blur effect on it, kind of like in art software that will have a blur on the outside of the circle or rectangle.

I didn't really try because I could not find a single page or video on it.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180147/in-built-method-flag-for-applying-gaussian-blur-to-objects-drawn-by-graphics2d/43199148#43199148); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661152/how-to-show-original-image-and-blurred-image-in-jframe/26661415#26661415)

Comment: The easy way is the way more people complain about.  Create a tiny image and magnify it 10x.  it will display blurry.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "gaussian blur" if that helps your search efforts

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

There is no functionality that can do this out of the box. You can give this method a try:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Main {
    public static void fillBlurredBorderRect(Graphics g, Color c, int x,
            int y, int width, int height, int horizBlurSize,
            int vertBlurSize) {
        Color previousColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(c);//from  w w  w . j  a  v  a  2s .  c om
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        if (vertBlurSize > 0) {
            int vertAlphaStep = previousColor.getAlpha() / vertBlurSize;
            for (int i = 1; i <= vertBlurSize; ++i) {
                g.setColor(setColorAlpha(previousColor, g.getColor()
                        .getAlpha() - vertAlphaStep));
                g.drawLine(x, y - i, x + width - 1, y - i);
                g.drawLine(x, y + height + i - 1, x + width - 1, y + height
                        + i - 1);
            }
        }

        if (horizBlurSize > 0) {
            g.setColor(previousColor);
            int vertAlphaStep = previousColor.getAlpha() / vertBlurSize;
            for (int i = 1; i <= horizBlurSize; ++i) {
                g.setColor(setColorAlpha(previousColor, g.getColor()
                        .getAlpha() - vertAlphaStep));
                g.drawLine(x - i, y, x - i, y + height - 1);
                g.drawLine(x + width + i - 1, y, x + width + i - 1, y
                        + height - 1);
            }
        }

    }

    public static Color setColorAlpha(Color c, int alpha) {
        if (alpha > 255 || alpha < 0)
            return c;
        return new Color(c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), alpha);
    }
}
```

**Solution 1:**

Use an image with `graphics.drawImage()` instead of a filled rect.

**Solution 2:**

Paint transparent components on top of your component.

**Additional informations:**

You may want to check out this resources:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ImageEffectSharpenblur.htm

[create an transparent rectangle over blurred background in jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215415/create-an-transparent-rectangle-over-blurred-background-in-jframe)

Comment: I have figured it out